# What is the meaning of "external recognition in quantity"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> No wonder that the culture descended to ostentatious displays of wealth, or in the parlance of Marx and Veblen, to commodity fetishism and conspicuous consumption. For a writer or an artist, in fact, **external recognition in quantity** - fame, to give it a title - could take the place of money or nearly so.

Dose it mean: apparent recognition?

This context is a little unclear to me if you make it more clear to me I would be very Thankful?

Thanks before hand.

Answer (score 1):

The text explains it already.

Question: What is the meaning of “external recognition in quantity”?

Answer: Fame (to give it a title/name)

Comment: Thanks. But I want to know what is the meaning of "external" in this context. can we replace it with other word like "superficial"

Comment: @Viser Hashemi: ***External recognition*** here means recognition ***by the outside world at large*** (as opposed to being well-known to your family, friends, local townspeople, etc.). Nothing to do with appearances or "superficiality".

Answer (score 0):

The phrase **in quantity** could be understood to mean "in large numbers".

> Do you have any blood oranges?
>   -- Yes, we just got a shipment. We have them in quantity.